# How do I make yarn work with trap and sudo?

Tags: bash, yarnpkg, interrupt

Given the following code

```
$ yarn --version
1.22.17
$ cat package.json 
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "outer": "./outer.sh"
    }
}
$ cat outer.sh 
#!/bin/bash

trap '' INT
./inner.sh

sudo echo "Cleaning up"
$ cat inner.sh 
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop..."
    sleep 1
done
```

I have outer.sh that starts inner.sh, which runs forever until CTRL-C. I want outer.sh to do some cleanup despite/after CTRL-C. It works fine as is with the trap. Now that cleanup code needs to run as root, hence the sudo. If I run "./outer.sh" like that from a terminal and press CTRL-C, I am prompted for the password, and the cleanup code executes hereafter. As I would expect. Now I run "./outer.sh" indirectly by doing "yarn outer". When I press CTRL-C I get the prompt for the password, but the entire process is exited immediately hereafter, and I never get to actually type the password, and the cleanup code never runs.

What can I do to make this work, so that when running "yarn outer", pressing CTRL-C, I am prompted for the password, it awaits my typing, and the cleanup code is executed hereafter?